# iOS / Beacons - How to fire didEnterRegion when turning on Bluetooth?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ibeacon

I have set up an application using ibeacons, and I notice that `didEnterRegion` is never fired when I turn on Bluetooth while inside the region. It however works fine when I physically enter the region with the Bluetooth on.

When in foreground, I tricked this behavior by calling `[self.locationManager requestStateForRegion:self.beaconRegion]` in `didStartMonitoringForRegion`, and checking I was inside.

However, I don't know what to do in background. I understand that the only method that could be fired is `didEnterRegion`, which would mean that I can't send a notification when just turning on Bluetooth inside a region.

Did someone managed to do that?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One idea that comes to mind: add `bluetooth-central` background mode to your app, and implement the `CBCentralManager` and `CBCentralManagerDelegate`'s [`centralManagerDidUpdateState`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreBluetooth/Reference/CBCentralManagerDelegate_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/CBCentralManagerDelegate/centralManagerDidUpdateState:). This should wake your app whenever Bluetooth is enabled or disabled, and you can use this time to `requestStateForRegion`.

Answer (score 0):

You can force to get notification didEnterRegion on enabling BLE by specifying notifyEntryStateOnDisplay in your region initialization:

`_myBeaconRegion.notifyEntryStateOnDisplay=YES;`

Comment: I have already included `self.beaconRegion.notifyEntryStateOnDisplay = Yes;` in my AppDelegate, so unfortunately I think this does not solve my issue